# Braid not colliding with clothing (Curve Problem?)

Tags: animation, rigging, soft-body

UPDATE: I noticed during the animation the curve the armature is following stretches out and although is still attached to its origin point keeps falling. Is there a way to keep the curve from stretching so much?

I am currently working on a model that uses a softbody on a curve that controls bones on an armature (like in a tail.) I got everything to work except when I run the animation the braid does not collide with the clothing on the mesh (no clothing modifier is applied, the dress is controlled by the armature). In fact, the settings for the soft body act differently once they were parented to the rig. (on previous tests I did get this to function.)

You can see in the attached picture that the braid is disappearing into the clothing. I tried putting various collision objects in front of it but nothing responded, which leads me to believe it is a problem with the braid
[image]

You can download the .blend file here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yH3EeGiUo4bkxmV2kzMkZvazg/view?usp=sharing

I would really appreciate any advice, I have been working on this for days!

Comment: I had a look at your blend file, nice work. A couple of suggestions, your soft body physics are applied to the curve controlling your armature, and not the braid mesh as I would have expected. If you start blender from the command line the look at the output after loading your blend file there is a dependency loop reported " Dependency cycle detected:
  braidCurve depends on MandanWoman30 through Bone Parent
  MandanWoman30 depends on braidCurve through Spline IK.".

Comment: It is my understanding that the soft body is on the curve because it is controlling the swing of the armature. I did try several tests where I added various physics to the braid but so far I have not gotten anything to work. Can you expand more on what a 'dependency cycle' is?